# Spring Data JPA @Query annotation, nativeQuery = true,

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have problem with my `@Repository`:

```
@Repository
public interface RekvZmRepository extends CrudRepository<RekvalZamestn, RekvalZamestnPk> {
@Query(value = "SELECT z.* FROM rek_zm d INNER JOIN proj_a a ON d.id = a.prj_idcislo"
  + "                                   INNER JOIN proj_e e ON a.id = e.id"
  + "                                   INNER JOIN rekv_z z ON d.id = z.id"
  + "WHERE  d.id = ?1 AND a.id = ?2 AND e.id = ?3", nativeQuery = true)
public List<RekvalZamestn> getRekvOsOnDoh(Long dhzmrk, Long prj, Long prje);
}
```

When I run it, result is:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not
extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

When I run `SQL` it works, so for me it looks like problem is not with `SQL` but with my `@Query`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query, in one-line format (condensing multiple spaces to one space for reasons of, erm, space), equates to

```
SELECT z.* FROM rek_zm d INNER JOIN proj_a a ON d.id = a.prj_idcislo INNER JOIN proj_e e ON a.id = e.id INNER JOIN rekv_z z ON d.id = z.idWHERE  d.id = ?1 AND a.id = ?2 AND e.id = ?3
```

If you concatenate all the strings in one line like this, it becomes obvious that you are missing a space before the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

change `SELECT z.* FROM` to `SELECT z FROM` assuming `RekvalZamestn` class maps to table `rekv_z`.

Comment: yes, `RekvalZamestn` maps to table `rekv_z` but it's native query. changing `z.*` to only `z` doesn't works (tested now).